# Взять регулярным выражением значение в скобках

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Строка:

```
td&gt; 1334 (50.00 %)
```

Пишу регулярку:

```
^.*?\(\d+.\d+.*?
```

Любые символы `.*?` до скобки `\(` далее нужное число `\d+.\d+` далее не нужные символы `.*?`

До открывающейся скобки могут быть разные символы разное количество.

Такая регулярка не работает. Что неправильно?

На выходе результат должен быть таким `50.00`

Comment: Какой язык (программирования)?

Comment: Язык програмирования PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что нужно на выход, - заворачиваем в скобки.
Начинаем с цифр после символа открытой скобки.
Потом символ точки и ещё цифры.
Пока не встретим пробел, табуляцию или еще что-то.

Например:

```
\((\d+\.\d+)\s
```

Можно заканчивать не пробельным символом, а "нецифрой":

```
\((\d+\.\d+)\D
```

Песочница: https://regex101.com/r/UlrpBR/1

Answer (score 2):

Используйте

```
 ^.*?\(\K\d+\.\d+
```

[Демо](https://regex101.com/r/OKsj7C/2)

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `.*?` - 0 и более символов, отличных от знаков перехода строки, как можно меньшее кол-во повторений
- `\(` - (
- `\K` - оператор, удаляющий весь текст из текущего совпадения
- `\d+` - 1 и более цифр
- `\.`  - точка
- `\d+` - 1+ цифр

Если число может быть целым, используйте `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` вместо `\d+\.\d+`.

Answer (score 1):

Если не нужно обрабатывать все что идет до числа, то вот так можно

`(?<=\()\d+.\d+`

Answer (score 1):

Смотря где вы это будете использовать. В общем случаем можно использовать Look behind и look ahead.

```
(?<=\()[\.\d]+(?=.*\))
```

Для случая с JS такое работать не будет, потому что там нет look behind. Но зато там есть группы, если я не ошибаюсь это будет так:

```
\(([\.\d]+)
```